# I want to include HttpContext.Current.Request in my windows forms

Tags: c#

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{    
    string json= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList = (List<DeSerialiseBL>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request[json], typeof(List<DeSerialiseBL>));
}
```

i want to deserialize the json value.so i use the above code.when i build 'Request is not exist in the current context' error displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 string Url = "Your Url";

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(Url).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer tmp = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        RemoteResult r = (RemoteResult)tmp.Deserialize(JsonResult, typeof(RemoteResult));
         // r.myDeserializedObjList is your desired output
    }
```

and create class for your desired result.That is

```
public class RemoteResult
    {
        List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to use the new HttpClient in my windows application .NET 4.5, but Visual Studio complains that it doesn't exist. I have System.Net.

Comment: i cannot install System.Net.Http. My NuGet version is 2.8.

Comment: Script is not existing in the current context error displayed

Comment: add System.Web.Extensions.dll from Visual studio.And try other two answers.

Comment: System.Web.Extensions is not available in the refernce library

Comment: create a class named RemoteResult with List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList; and i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the code in your question, you're successfully deserializing the JSON string you receive from a web request you issue through HttpWebRequest.

Say the response contains `{ "foo" : "bar" }`, then that's the value the variable `json` contains.

But the expression `Request[json]` that follows it, makes no sense. I can assure you that the request variables do not contain a key called `{ "foo" : "bar" }`, so the expression `Request[json]` returns an empty string.

You should not use `Request` there, but directly pass the `json` variable:

```
List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList = 
    (List<DeSerialiseBL>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<DeSerialiseBL>));
```

The code can be further simplified:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // At the top of your file

var myDeserializedObjList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeSerialiseBL>>(json);
```

So you don't need HttpRequest.Current, because the json string has no relation at all to the current request.

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: Yeah that's a whole nother problem: the JSON structure does not match your class `DeSerialiseBL`. Use http://json2csharp.com to create classes that match the JSON.

Comment: var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                
                List<RootObject> myDeserializedObjList = (List<RootObject>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(List<RootObject>));
     }

Comment: public class Product
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Product> products { get; set; }
        public int success { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can not use HttpContext.Current  in win form. winform not running in request pipeline..

DeserializeObject waiting serialize string and type..

```
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {    
         string json= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
         //List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList = (List<DeSerialiseBL>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request[json], typeof(List<DeSerialiseBL>));
         List<DeSerialiseBL> myDeserializedObjList = (List<DeSerialiseBL>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<DeSerialiseBL>));
    }
```

Comment: when i executed this code 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' error displayed